# Removing coordinate singularities

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, singularity

Consider the Riemannian metric given in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wfgw.png). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_instanton#List_of_examples) claims that this Riemannian manifold has the topology $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^2$, but the coordinate expression given in the picture seems to be only smooth and non-singular for $r>r_0$ and $0<\theta<\pi$, giving a Riemannian metric on $$(r_0,\infty)\times S^1\times(S^2\setminus\{N,S\})\cong(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})\times(S^2\setminus\{N,S\}),$$ where $N$ and $S$ are the north and south poles on $S^2$. Since Wikipedia claims the topology is $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^2$, my guess is that the singularities at $\theta=0$, $\theta=\pi$ and $r=r_0$ are just coordinate singularities. I want to show this more rigorously. In other words, I want to show that the metric in the picture extends smoothly to a Riemannian metric on all of $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^2$, and my guess is that one would have to come up with a clever choice of new coordinates in which these singularities vanish. But how does one approach the problem of coming up with such coordinates?

Comment: The singularity in the Kerr metric is a ring rather than a point, so the appropriate topological space would be $(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1)\times\mathbb{R}$. This singularity apears in [Kerr-Schild coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#Kerr%E2%80%93Schild_coordinates).

Comment: @Kajelad Are you talking about the Euclidean version of the metric (i.e. the one in the picture I linked)? The page you linked seems to talk about the Lorenzian version of the metric.

Comment: My mistake; Kerr-Schild coordinates will not automatically work in the Euclidean case. That said, KS coordinates could still be used to identify coordinate singularities by smoothly extending the tetrad across them.